# Using individual bands from multi-band image in ArcGIS raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I'm trying to use individual bands from a multi-band TM image (IMG file) within the raster calculator in ArcGIS 10 (SP2/3).

I can add individual bands to my MXD, but raster calculator will only use Band 1 regardless of how I reference the layers from the MXD.

Using something like `"TM_Image.img - Layer_3" - 0` in the raster calculator will run, but will use Band 1.

Using the full path to the image works correctly but is unwieldy for longer expressions/paths.  Like `"X:\TM_Image.img\Layer_3" - 0`

I think this worked in earlier versions of Arc 10, but no longer on SP 2 or 3.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the Image analysis window? I know it gives you less control, but still allows for some useful calculations.  And it is computationally more efficient - so if your dealing with a large data-set it may speed things up for you.

Little Tutorial I put together.

http://www.thadwester.com/1/post/2012/05/ndvi-calculation-in-arcgis-10.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you HAVE to use full paths in ArcGIS10.  It doesn't seem help to specify the default geodatabase in the map document properties to try shortening the path (I tried that too).

Comment: Thanks!  I hope this is improved in newer versions of ArcMap, but this is a good workaround...