# Multiply a stack of floating point rasters( composite raster ) with a constant

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster-calculator

I am trying to multiply a floating point stack of rasters (10 layers) with a constant and round up to the next integer. I have the formula RoundUp(10*composite_raster) in raster calculator, but for some reason the output raster has only 1 band while i expect 10 bands? Can you please suggest any way to multiply the composite raster by a constant ?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20651/using-individual-bands-from-a-multi-band-image-in-arcgis-10-raster-calculator

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the [Times tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000009p000000.htm) on each band and then combine the individual rasters into one raster using the [Composite Bands](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009p000000) tool. Essentially to multiply each band, when adding the raster to the Times tool, double click on the raster filename again like you would open a folder. Then you'll see all the bands.